# Fetching the API_ID and API_HASH from telegram programmatically using python

Tags: python-3.x, backend, telegram, telegram-bot

I've been trying to fetch the API_ID and API_HASH from telegram programmatically using python.
I was able to Create a session and log in programmatically. here is the code:

```
import requests, random, json

send_password_headers = {
"authority": "my.telegram.org",
"method": "POST",
"path": "/auth/send_password",
"scheme": "https",
"Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Content-Length": "21",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Origin": "https://my.telegram.org",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Referer": "https://my.telegram.org/auth?to=apps",
"Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\"",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
s=requests.session()
number=str(int(input('Please Enter your number 
Including Country Code: ')))
num_url='https://my.telegram.org/auth/send_password'
num_data={'phone': number}

random_hash_response=s.post(num_url, data=num_data, 
headers=send_password_headers)
if 'random_hash' in str(random_hash_response.content):
    value = json.loads(random_hash_response.content.decode("utf-8"))["random_hash"]
    print(value)
    otp_url='https://my.telegram.org/auth/login'
    otp_data={
        'phone': number,
        'random_hash': value,
        'password': input("Please enter the login code here: ")
    }
    login_headers=send_password_headers
    login_headers['path']="/auth/login"
    login_headers["Content-Length"]="73"

    login_response=s.post(otp_url, data=otp_data, headers=login_headers)
    print(login_response.content)
else:
  print(random_hash_response.content)
```

The login response is = b'true'
now:
1.i need to go to my.telegram.org/apps.
2.then fill the form and submit.
3.upon submitting i can extract the API_ID and API_HASH.

problem is:
the payload for this link: "https://my.telegram.org/apps/create"
looks like this:

```
hash: 2d5d8ecfe2eba66183
app_title: title
app_shortname: title
app_url: www.telegram.org
app_platform: other
app_desc: title
```

i'm confused about that 'hash' part. i'm not sure how can i get it programmatically so that i can send a post request and fetch the data.

**Can someone help me out about this??**

Answer (score 0):

i found out how can i achive this. here is the code for further reference.

```
import requests, random, json,string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def word_gen():
    word = ""
    for i in range(random.randint(5,9)):
        word += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return word
def sentence_generator():
    sentence = ""
    for i in range(random.randint(5,9)):
        sentence += word_gen() + " "
    return sentence
def get_details():
  send_password_headers = {
      "authority": "my.telegram.org",
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/auth/send_password",
      "scheme": "https",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Length": "21",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "Origin": "https://my.telegram.org",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Referer": "https://my.telegram.org/auth?to=apps",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\"",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
  }
  s=requests.session()
  number=str(int(input('Please Enter your number Including Country Code: ')))
  num_url='https://my.telegram.org/auth/send_password'
  num_data={'phone': number}

  random_hash_response=s.post(num_url, data=num_data, headers=send_password_headers)
  if 'random_hash' in str(random_hash_response.content):
      value = json.loads(random_hash_response.content.decode("utf-8"))["random_hash"]
      print(value)
      otp_url='https://my.telegram.org/auth/login'
      otp_data={
          'phone': number,
          'random_hash': value,
          'password': input("Please enter the login code here: ")
      }
      login_headers=send_password_headers
      login_headers['path']="/auth/login"
      login_headers["Content-Length"]="73"

      login_response=s.post(otp_url, data=otp_data, headers=login_headers)
      print(login_response.content)
      if 'true' in str(login_response.content):
        app_page_url='https://my.telegram.org/apps'
        res=s.get(app_page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        span_tag = soup.find_all('span',{ 'class':'form-control input-xlarge uneditable-input','onclick':'this.select();'})
        if span_tag:
            api_id,api_hash=span_tag[0].text,span_tag[1].text
            return {'id':api_id, 'hash':api_hash}
        else:
          create_app_url='https://my.telegram.org/apps/create'
          hash = soup.find('input', {'name': 'hash'})['value']
          app_data={
            'hash': hash,
            'app_title': word_gen(),
            'app_shortname': word_gen(),
            'app_url': 'www.telegram.org',
            'app_platform': 'other',
            'app_desc': sentence_generator()
          }
          app_headers= {
              'authority': 'my.telegram.org',
              'method': 'POST',
              'path': '/apps/create',
              'scheme': 'https',
              'accept': '*/*',
              'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
              'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
              'cache-control': 'no-cache',
              'content-length': '131',
              'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
              'cookie': 'stel_token=f37997f6c80643759626bd4903b4e225f37997faf379dcca9a2f23b59041face2f7ab',
              'origin': 'https://my.telegram.org',
              'pragma': 'no-cache',
              'referer': 'https://my.telegram.org/apps',
              'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
              'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
              'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
              'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
              'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
              'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
              'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0',
              'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          }
          s.post(create_app_url,data=app_data,headers=app_headers)
          res=s.get(app_page_url)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
          span_tag = soup.find_all('span',{ 'class':'form-control input-xlarge uneditable-input','onclick':'this.select();'})
          api_id,api_hash=span_tag[0].text,span_tag[1].text
          return {'id':api_id, 'hash':api_hash}
```

this will take the number and otp of the user and return the api_id and api_hash for further user with telethon or other libraries.